# Webpack dev server returns 404 Error with Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a typescript project, When I run `npm start` the browser won't open and my `vscode` console shows no error and compiles successfully, everything seems good, when I manually go to `http://localhost:8080/` in the console I faced an 404 error:

> Get localhost:8080/ 404 (Not Found)

[This is my project's structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBje9.jpg)

**webpack.config.js**:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: 'dist',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
};
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

**package.json**:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "webpack": "^5.80.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.3"
  }
}
```

and this is the `script` tag in my `html` file:

```html
<script type="module" src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

What is wrong with this configs?

Comment: Try setting `publicPath` to `/` and `src="bundle.js"`.

Comment: I try that too, but still got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to insert the `<script>` tag to the html template manually. [html-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) can do this for you.

> The plugin will generate an HTML5 file for you that includes all your webpack bundles in the body using script tags.

project directory structure:

```bash
✗ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
├── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── app.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js

1 directory, 6 files
```

`src/app.ts`:

```
console.log('test')
```

`index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/app.ts',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  devServer: {
    static: './dist',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'index.html' })
  ]
};
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --open",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "webpack": "^5.80.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.3"
  }
}
```

Run `npm start`, access `http://localhost:8080/` and check the console of the browser, get log:

```
test
```